# LINQ with Contains return zero rows if i am passing empty string

Tags: c#, linq

i don't know how to handle this in LINQ
simply i  have a searchKey in which i am passing user enter data and it return with rows. but if i am not passing any searchkey it not given any data. i dont want to add contains if searchkey is empty :(

```
var AppointmentList = (from app in Con.ios_Appointment
                       where (app.IS_DELETED == false && app.CLINICIANID == appReq.id
                       && app.FNAME.Contains(appReq.searchKey.Trim()) || app.LNAME.Contains(appReq.searchKey.Trim()) || app.ADDRESS.Contains(appReq.searchKey.Trim())
                       )
                       orderby app.DATE descending
                       select new
                       {
                           app.ID,
                           app.FNAME,
                           app.LNAME,
                           app.DATE,
                           app.LONGITUDE,
                           app.LATITUDE,
                           app.ADDRESS,
                           app.STATUS,
                           app.START_TIME

                       }).Skip(skipRecord).Take(Convert.ToInt32(record)).ToList();
```

Comment: As an aside, I'd strongly recommend that you start following .NET naming conventions - your code will look a lot more idiomatic that way.

Comment: You can split where condition1 && condition2 && condition3 into 3 wheres : where condition1 where condition2 where condition3. that may improve the readibility of your query

Comment: @JonSkeet - thanks for your advice. its client requirement to give object names in capital :(

Comment: @ketan: Within the C# code, not just the database? Wow, that's just awful.

Comment: @JonSkeet even database columns names :)

Comment: The database column names is fine - but forcing those column names as C# properties against .NET conventions is nasty (as is `ios_Appentment`...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use method syntax to easily build the query up programatically:

```cs
var query = Con.ios_Appointment.Where(app => !app.IS_DELETED && app.CLINICIANID == appReq.id);
var search = appReq.searchKey.Trim();
if (search != "")
{
    query = query.Where(app => app.FNAME.Contains(search) || 
                               app.LNAME.Contains(search) ||
                               app.ADDRESS.Contains(search));
}
var appointments = query
    .OrderByDescending(app => app.DATE)
    .Select(app => new
    {
        app.ID,
        app.FNAME,
        app.LNAME,
        app.DATE,
        app.LONGITUDE,
        app.LATITUDE,
        app.ADDRESS,
        app.STATUS,
        app.START_TIME 
    })
    .Skip(skipRecord)
    .Take(Convert.ToInt32(record))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This is what I was starting to write as an answer :-) ! Would this be even better with:
`var search = appReq.searchKey?.Trim() ?? "";` so that it also handles a null searchKey?

Comment: @asidis: I'd only add that if I knew that `appReq.searchKey` might legitimately be null - I *suspect* it won't be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` method:

```
 where (app.IS_DELETED == false &&
          app.CLINICIANID == appReq.id && 
          (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(appReq.searchKey) || 
           app.FNAME.Contains(appReq.searchKey.is Trim()) || ...
```